# Creating string from Custom label

Tags: string, salesforce, apex, sfdc

I have a custom label in CSV format called Test having value abc, xyz and I want to create a string in the form 'abc','xyz'. How would we do that?

Code Written so far

String str = System.Label.Test;
// next steps

Comment: Please add more context to your question. If in doubt review [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below splits the label at the comma to create a list. Each string in the list is them trimmed to remove whitespace and added to another list. That list is joined using ',' as the delimiter.

```
String str = System.Label.Test; // next steps
final String SINGLE_QUOTE = '\'';
final String COMMA = ',';
final String DELIMITER = SINGLE_QUOTE + COMMA + SINGLE_QUOTE;
String formattedLabel = SINGLE_QUOTE;
List<String> stringItems = new List<String>();

for(String item : str.split(',')){
    stringItems.add(item.trim());
}
formattedLabel += String.join(stringItems, DELIMITER);
formmatedLabel += SINGLE_QUOTE;
System.debug(formattedLabel);
```